# Acquiring unique time stamp with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I`m trying to use performance.now() function in JavaScript to acquire unique time stamp for each PC.
The way I do this is by measuring how long certain operations take.
Is there possible way to create certain tasks that will take different time on each computer but will be the same every time that they run on the specific PC ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can create an operation which will have the exact tsd each time on the same pc, if you want to identify the machine you should use cookies

Comment: Does it have to be a timestamp or you want to generate any kind of unique fingerprint of a machine?

Comment: The latter. I`m trying to see the potential, but i`m new to JavaScript and can`t think of all possible ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need some kind of back-end to do this, or at least make sure that the time intervals are specified individually in advance.

It's likely that you can hook up the PCs to one another in some kind of peer-to-peer arrangement, perhaps using the new-fangled RTC API (see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-rtcdatachannel).

Complete millisecond timing accuracy may be elusive, however, but if you can live with a tolerance of (say) 10-20 milliseconds, you should be ok. Depends on what else the computer is doing, of course.